# Is there a numpy way to filter an array of arrays by a list of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have the numpy array `x` where `x` is

```py
x = np.array(
  [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
  ]
)
```

I also have a list of indices `i` where `i = [0, 1]`. I would like to get an array of the the value at index `n[i]` for every `n` in `x`.


The optimal output is

```py
np.array([1, 4])
```

This can very obviously be done with a for loop, but I was wondering if there was a simpler *numpy* way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexing:

```
x[np.arange(x.shape[0]), i]
```

output: `array([1, 4])`